# Subview acessing superview methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, subview, superview

How can a subview access the methods from its superview? I have a button, and when pressed I would like the button to call a method from its superview, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 2):

suppose your super View class name is

```
MainView.h
```

sub View Name

```
SubView.h
```

So In sub class you can do

```
MainView *myMainView = (Mainview *)[self superview];
[myMainView someMethod];
```

Make sure `someMethod` is public Method.

Other way you could have reference to all the view is set a tag
For example

```
myMainView.tag = 100; or self.tag = 100;
```

In the subview you could do

```
   MainView *myMainView = (Mainview *)[self viewWithTag:100];
   [myMainView someMethod];
```

Answer (score 1):

### a weird construct but just call the method:

inside a view you have have `self.superview`

since self.superview is a UIView*, the compiler will claim it is invalid to call method XYZ on it. Cast it to id or to your class name to use it

### e.g.

`[(id)self.superview myMethod];`

or even

`id myValue = [(id)self.superview myMethod:param1];`

---

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use delegates.

```
@protocol ButtonHandlingDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) subviewButtonWasPressed;
@end
```

In your Subview add this:
    @property (nonatomic, weak) id selectionDelegate;

When subview is created, set delegate to superview.

Define Superview as delegate in  .h file

```
@interface SuperView : UIView <ButtonHandlingDelegate>
```

in Superview .m file

```
- (void) subviewButtonWasPressed{
     // Do somethign about it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers listed are hacky and bad style. You should be using delegation through the subview's ViewController. What you will want to do is create a protocol for your subview with a void method called something like `specialButtonPressedOnView:(SUBVIEWCLASS *)view`. Then in the subview's view controller you should make yourself the delegate for this protocol and respond to the delegate method from the VC's context.

Using self.superview is a bad idea because you cannot guarantee what your superview is going to be and generally blindly calling method on objects (ESPECIALLY those cast to id) is a really bad idea.

The other answer that suggested having the superview implement the subview's protocol is also not good style because you're creating a dependency between your views. If you were thinking of going down this path your subview should probably just be a subclass of the superview.

One of the core parts of the MVC design pattern is making sure that your views are reusable and totally independent. They are just structures that you can inject your content into, to which they will respond with pretty UI, and they don't need to know anything about what's being passed to them and don't have to ask other views for help. So either using delegation through the subview's ViewController or subclassing is probably the best direction. Both methods preserve the MVC pattern and are much safer than the other suggestions.

Comment: I agree mostly which is what I aimed to express with 'weird construct.' -- BUT I have also long stopped to see MVC as such B/W world -- there ARE situations where you want to against the rules. e.g. when you build a view which is in fact 1 containerview and N subviews and where you don't want to expose the subviews.